# Thymeleaf and Micronaut Views error when using Layout dialect

Tags: thymeleaf, micronaut

We are running Micronaut with Thymeleaf views and the Layout dialect (we add it manually by overriding Micronaut's `ThymeleafFactory`). Below are the dependencies (Micronaut version is 3.2.7):

```
implementation 'io.micronaut.views:micronaut-views-core:3.1.2'
implementation 'io.micronaut.views:micronaut-views-thymeleaf:3.1.2'
implementation 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:3.0.0'
```

The problematic code is this:

```html
<html layout:decorate="~{/layout-top}">
```

This seems to work fine when running with `./gradlew run`, but crashes when running from a fat (shadow) jar using `java -jar ...`. This would point to classpath issues, but we couldn't figure out what would those be.

Below the error message when running the shadow jar:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: io.micronaut.views.thymeleaf.WebEngineContext.getOrCreate() is applicable for argument types: (String, nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.context.extensions.IContextExtensions$_getPrefixForDialect_closure1) values: [DialectPrefix::org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect, nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.context.extensions.IContextExtensions$_getPrefixForDialect_closure1@26b0c4d0]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.context.extensions.IContextExtensions.getPrefixForDialect(IContextExtensions.groovy:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ReflectionMetaMethod.invoke(ReflectionMetaMethod.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.NewInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(NewInstanceMetaMethod.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.models.extensions.IProcessableElementTagExtensions.equalsIgnoreXmlnsAndWith(IProcessableElementTagExtensions.groovy:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ReflectionMetaMethod.invoke(ReflectionMetaMethod.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.NewInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(NewInstanceMetaMethod.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.decorators.DecorateProcessor.doProcess(DecorateProcessor.groovy:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.java:77)
```

We debugged this and isolated the failing code in `nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.context.extensions.IContextExtensions`:

```
    static String getPrefixForDialect(IContext self, Class<IProcessorDialect> dialectClass) {
        return self.getOrCreate(DIALECT_PREFIX_PREFIX + dialectClass.name) { ->
            def dialectConfiguration = self.configuration.dialectConfigurations.find { dialectConfig ->
                return dialectClass.isInstance(dialectConfig.dialect)
            }
            return dialectConfiguration?.prefixSpecified ?
                    dialectConfiguration?.prefix :
                    dialectConfiguration?.dialect?.prefix
        }
    }
```

It *seems* that the `IContext` argument is not what's supposed to be, but we couldn't really find the root cause for this. Nor why this is behaving differently with the two different methods of running the same code.

Answer (score 5):

Upon further investigation, we discovered that this is related to this bug in the shadow jar plugin: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/490

The library `thymeleaf-layout-dialect` is using a `nz.net.ultraq.extensions:groovy-extensions:1.1.0`
which, in turn, registers some Groovy extensions through `META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule`

The shadow jar plugin doesn't handle these correctly (it only handles `META-INF/groovy/...` paths).

As per ticket comments here https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/490 , there is a workaround, but it's deeply unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading my Gradle Version

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.6.4
```

(You might need an other version than 7.6.4, but for me it was the most feasible)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting “No signature of method: org.thymeleaf.context.EngineContext.getOrCreate” when using the Thymeleaf Layout dialect. I was trying to use the maven assembly plugin to package all my project’s classes into a single executable jar. I ended up having to give up on that, and I instead produced 2 jars. One was a jar with my non-thymeleaf-layout dependencies. The other was the thymeleaf layout dialect jar. I added both jars to my class path and specified my main class, and it started working